# sort multi demension list by another single list in python

Tags: python, list

I have lists like this.

first : (apple, durian, cherry, egg, banana)

second : ((banana,b1,b2,b3,b4),
          (durian,d1,d2,d3,d4),
          (apple,a1,a2,a3,a4),
          (egg,e1,e2,e3,e4),
          (cherry,c1,c2,c3,c4))

I want to arrange second list using first list.
So I expect this.

```
     ((apple,a1,a2,a3,a4),
      (durian,d1,d2,d3,d4),
      (cherry,c1,c2,c3,c4),
      (egg,e1,e2,e3,e4),
      (banana,b1,b2,b3,b4))
```

please let me know how to do this.
thanks.

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: FYI: you have tuples, not lists

Comment: inspectorG4dget : I see. in fact I realized it later though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [25]: d = {L[0]:list(L[1:]) for L in second}

In [26]: answer = [[k]+d[k] for k in first]

In [27]: answer
Out[27]: 
[['apple', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['durian', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'],
 ['cherry', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
 ['egg', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4'],
 ['banana', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']]
```

Comment: Thank you, I got yours. It works well. :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all - those are tuples, secondly all the samples you gave are not actually strings, so I did that for you.

**Now lets convert it to a dictionary first:**

```
data = [('banana','b1','b2','b3','b4'),
        ('durian','d1','d2','d3','d4'),
        ('apple','a1','a2','a3','a4'),
        ('egg','e1','e2','e3','e4'),
        ('cherry','c1','c2','c3','c4')]

data = {t[0]:t for t in data}  # make dictionary with dictionary comprehension.
```

**No we have our selector:**

```
selector = ['apple', 'durian', 'cherry', 'egg', 'banana']
```

**Then we order and create the list:**

```
results = [data[key] for key in selector]  # order result by selector
```

**Answer:**

```
[('apple', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'), 
 ('durian', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'), 
 ('cherry', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'), 
 ('egg', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4'), 
 ('banana', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4')]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a dictionary? You could try this:

```
# first : (apple, durian, cherry, egg, banana)
# second : ((banana,b1,b2,b3,b4), (durian,d1,d2,d3,d4), (apple,a1,a2,a3,a4), (egg,e1,e2,e3,e4), (cherry,c1,c2,c3,c4))

d = {}
for lst in second:
    d[lst[0]] = lst

result = []
for item in first:
    # you shall ensure that key `item` exists in `d`
    result.append(d[item])
```